# Sorting lists when there are no leading zeros

Tags: text-processing, sort

I would like to sort this numerically and the sort command keys off the first character.

```
CPL_V11.01.00_1
CPL_V11.01.00_10
CPL_V11.01.00_2
CPL_V11.01.00_3
CPL_V11.01.00_35
CPL_V11.01.00_36
CPL_V11.01.00_37
CPL_V11.01.00_38
CPL_V11.01.00_39
CPL_V11.01.00_4
CPL_V11.01.00_40
CPL_V11.01.00_41
CPL_V11.01.00_42
CPL_V11.01.00_43
CPL_V11.01.00_44
CPL_V11.01.00_45
CPL_V11.01.00_46
CPL_V11.01.00_47
```

What should I do here?

Comment: sorrry for the missing CR/LF

Answer (score 11):

```
sort -V input
```

from `man sort`:

```
   -V, --version-sort
       natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

that will get you:

```
CPL_V11.01.00_1
CPL_V11.01.00_2
CPL_V11.01.00_3
CPL_V11.01.00_4
CPL_V11.01.00_10
CPL_V11.01.00_35
CPL_V11.01.00_36
CPL_V11.01.00_37
CPL_V11.01.00_38
CPL_V11.01.00_39
CPL_V11.01.00_40
CPL_V11.01.00_41
CPL_V11.01.00_42
CPL_V11.01.00_43
CPL_V11.01.00_44
CPL_V11.01.00_45
CPL_V11.01.00_46
```

You can also use:

```
sort -t _ -k 3 -n input
```

(split on `_` and use the 3rd field sorted by number)

Comment: am using cygwin and sort -t _ -k 3 -n input works best