# How to sort lines that contain "_" numerically?

Tags: sort

Here's a subset of the file names in my file:

```
profile_10_1_1
profile_10_1_2
profile_1_1_1
```

I'm trying to sort them numerically in ascending order, that is starting from 1 onwards. I used the following command

```
sort -n filename
```

and also tried this:

```
sort -nk filename
```

But the ones with 10 will always be at the top of the list.

How do I write a command to get this desired output:

```
profile_1_1_1
profile_1_1_2
....
profile_9_1_1
....
profile_10_1_1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [List files sorted numerically](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically)

Comment: @CedianO that question applies to single numbers, these are more like version numbers.

Comment: Yes indeed, but it works also here

Comment: See the last reply

Comment: See the reply of Volker Siegel

Comment: [Similar things](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169472/sorting-lists-when-there-are-no-leading-zeros) have been asked before though

Comment: Why don't they use the search?

Comment: Sorry that was an accidental edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FreeBSD and GNU `sort` have a `-V` option for that.

```
sort -V < filename
```

GNU `ls` has a `-v` option. So if those files do exist, you could do:

```
xargs -d '\n' < filename ls -dv --
```

`zsh` has parameter expansion flags to sort arrays numerically:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(fno)"$(<filename)"}
```

Otherwise, portably, you'd have to do it like:

```
sort -t_ -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n -k5,5n filename
```

Answer (score 3):

`-V` does exactly what you want.

```
-V, --version-sort
              natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

Works at least in GNU `sort`.